# jQuery SlideShow doesn't display all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8/">
        <title> Jquery </title>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


       <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "RizzStyle.css"/> 

   </head>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    function Slider() {

    $(".slider #1").show ("fade" , 500);

    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction : "left"}, 500);


    var sc = $("slider img").size();
    var count = 2;

   setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider#"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'}, 500);
        $(".slider#"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

        if ( count == sc ) {

            count = 1;

        }else {
            count = count+1;
        }


    },6500);
}



    </script>




    <body onload = "Slider();">


    <div id = "header">
        <h1> Jquery</h1>

    </div>  

        <div id = "container"> 

            <div  class = "slider" > 
             <img id = "1" src = "North.jpg" border = "0" alt = "North"/>
             <img id = "2" src = "Android.jpg" border = "0" alt = "Android"/>
             <img id = "3" src = "Wolf.jpg" border = "0" alt = "Wolf"/>


            </div>

            <div class = "shadow">

            </div>


        </div>

    </body>



</html>
```

Ok so im trying to create a slideshow in jQuery . the first image works fine as it has a smooth fade in and swipe out motion at the end, but as you can see I have three images and the other two doesn't appear so the screen is just blank with the default shadow image at the bottom (never mind that) Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between `.slider` and `id`. Without a space, the selector means an element with class `slider` and `id x`. However, a space means an element with class `slider` and descendant with `id x`.

```
 $(".slider #"+count)
```

```js
function Slider() {

    $(".slider #1").show ("fade" , 500);

    $(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction : "left"}, 500);


    var sc = $("slider img").size();
    var count = 2;

   setInterval(function(){
        $(".slider #"+count).show("slide",{direction:'right'}, 500);
        $(".slider #"+count).delay(5500).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);

        if ( count == sc ) {

            count = 1;

        }else {
            count = count+1;
        }


    },6500);
}
Slider();
```

```html
<meta charset = "utf-8/">
        <title> Jquery </title>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


       <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "RizzStyle.css"/> 



    <div id = "header">
        <h1> Jquery</h1>

    </div>  

        <div id = "container"> 

            <div  class = "slider" > 
             <img id = "1" src = "North.jpg" border = "0" alt = "North"/>
             <img id = "2" src = "Android.jpg" border = "0" alt = "Android"/>
             <img id = "3" src = "Wolf.jpg" border = "0" alt = "Wolf"/>


            </div>

            <div class = "shadow">

            </div>


        </div>
```

**Update**

Since all ids should be unique within a document, using the id by itself should be sufficient.

```
$("#"+count)
```

Comment: `.slider` is not needed at all since `#` is unique in any case. So instead of what you suggested `$(".slider #"+count)`  - this: `$("#"+count)` will suffice.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, you are right. I updated my answer. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I literally just figured that out a few seconds before this post lol Thankyou anyway how ever do you know how I can make it loop back to the first image? cause after the three images it just goes blank again.

Comment: @elmashrafi, I believe that qualifies for a seperate question. Anyways, hope my answer helped out(dont forget to mark it as accepted if it did).

Comment: Dont worry guys solved the issue just a minor spelling error with my css.